# Making multi-level menu in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make a multi-level dropdown style menu using only HTML and CSS. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="body">
    <div class="sidenav">
        <ul class="sidenavmenu">
            <li class="nav-header">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="Content/Images/logosmallest.gif" /></div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <span>
                        <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="Images/profpicpark.jpg"/>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <span class="name">Parker Green</span>
                <span class="text-muted">Web Designer</span>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope">
                    </i>Mailbox
                </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>test</li>
                            <li>test</li>
                            <li>test</li>
                        </ul>
            </li>
```

And the CSS:

```
.sidenav ul li ul {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 150px;
      top: 48px;
      left: 100px;
  }
  .sidenav ul li ul li {
      display: block;
  }
  .sidenav ul li:hover ul {
      display: block;
   }
```

The code thus far is very basic and hardly functional. I want the sub menu li to display on click or on hover. This menu is a side navigation, so I also need the rest of the menu to respond accordingly (moving down so the dropdown items don't run into other items).

Answer (score 0):

you can make an element appear by interacting with another element through css using the `>` operator. ie:

```
sidenavmenu {
display: none;
}
sidenav:hover > sidenavmenu {
display: block;
}
```

play around with that to get your desired effects